# Folder traversal with Spring MVC + Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have an application similar to Cloud Storages. I have a side treenav, it looks like the one on windows explorer. Next to it is a filebox where I want the folders and files to show for the particular folder I am on.

I have my mapping which returns the folders and files inside it.

Ex. localhost:8080/home/get-files?folderId=4

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody FolderShowDto getFiles(Principal principal, Integer folderId) {
    FolderShowDto folder = fileSystemService.getFolder(folderId, userDao.show(principal.getName()).getId());
    return folder;
}
```

How do I make my filebox update without reloading the page using Ajax?

Comment: If you use jquery, it should be something like : `$.ajax({
   url:"/home/get-files?folderId=4",
   type:"GET" });`

Comment: You need to set a time interval to call the ajax every 1 sec and update the view based on the new result.

Comment: How do I access the data returned from my mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax call should be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/home/get-files?folderId="+ currentFolderId,
        type : "GET",
        cache:false,
        success : function(resp) {
            // your data is here
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // handle errors here
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you, i based my code from this and followed through. I posted my code that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using @ResponseBody, my controller method will return my data as JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    headers : {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/home/get-files',
    data : 'folderId=4',
    success : function(response) {
        // access my data here
    },
    error : function() {
        // what happens if there is an error
    }
});
```